# dart: How to read/de-serilize the data buffer from HttpRequest.response into class objects

Tags: dart, dart-html

I have requested a binary file from the server and I want to de-serialize the data from this file into class objects. Below is my code. Could some one tell me if there is a more elegant and convenient way to do this for I have several different class objects.

```
    import 'dart:html';
    import 'dart:typed_data';

    class Header {
      final ByteData magic = new ByteData(3);
      int version;
      int minorVersion;
    ...// Other data members.
    }


    void main() {
      var path = 'url to a binary file';
      var request = new HttpRequest();
      request
        ..open('GET', path)
        ..responseType = 'arraybuffer'
        ..onLoadEnd.listen((e) => requestComplete(request))
        ..send();
    }

    void requestComplete(HttpRequest request) {
      if (request.status == 200) {
        print('headers: ${request.responseHeaders}');
        print('type: ${request.responseType}');

        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = request.response;

        var magic = byteBuffer.asUint8List(0, 3);
        print(new String.fromCharCodes(magic));

        var data = byteBuffer.asInt32List(4, 8);
        print(data);

...// Process other data
      } else {
        print('Request failed, status = ${request.status}');
      }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what this question is about. How do you serialize the classes on the server side? How is the binary data encoded?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Not the classes, but the data structures the class objects contains. The binary is dumped from another software. In some object oriented language, like c/c++, c#, java, etc, there are some kinds to methods to read back/de-serialize the data structures. But I didn't find a way in javascript and dart yet.

Comment: See my answer. If you provide more information what possibilities you have in your project I can elaborate a bit more on possible methods.

Answer (score 1):

> The binary is dumped from another software. In some object oriented language, like c/c++, c#, java, etc, there are some kinds to methods to read back/de-serialize the data structures. But I didn't find a way in javascript and dart yet

This sounds like a language specific encoding. There usually aren't libraries available for other languages to deserialize because the source language probably uses features/constructs that aren't available in the target language or can't be mapped 1:1.

If you can use a platform-neutral way to serialize in the first place there are several options

- JSON is used for this a lot, because it it language-independent but also somewhat limited.
- There are other cross-platform solutions like Googles Protocol Buffers and a lot of others with support for lots of programming languages.

You can of course decode the binary data in Dart, but you need to know how to interpret the binary data yourself and read and interpret it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. I get your points and I am considering using google's Protocol Buffers.